# Does giving props as {...props} instead of myProp={value} to a component re render that component?

Tags: reactjs

If I give some components props like:

```
<MyComponent {...props} />
```

Instead of

```
<MyComponent myProp={value} />
```

Where props may have some properties that this component does not use.

How the component knows what props have changed and if it should re-render based only on props it uses? Does it know at all?

Comment: Component re-renders only on state change

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava But the user might pass a state value down as a prop, and pass the props down to another component as {...props}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component re-renders if it's state or it's parent component props are changed/updated.

So suppose in case of `...props` there's an object of properties behind it as if one of the property gets changed, whole component will re-render due to that only one property change

**Does re-render**

```
let obj = {
  a : some value,
  b : some value, // gets changed
}
<Component {...obj} />
```

While supplying only one value to prop, incase if that value gets changed component will re-render on basis of that singleton change.

**Does not re-render**

```
let obj = {
  a : some value,
  b : some value, // gets changed
}
<Component myProp = {obj.a} />
```

So as Paul Habfast said in his answer that, even if `b` from `obj` is not used in component, change in it's value will trigger re-render as we have sent all properties as `...props` form.

**Note : Assume this `obj` is like set of properties that it might contain  component's state properties or any constants/primitive/non-primitive data type value**

Answer (score 1):

A `React.Component` by default rerenders whenever its parent component rerenders.

A `React.PureComponent` will rerender if any of any member of its props or state has changed.

A Functional component is a simplified `PureComponent` with no state, hence will rerender if any of its props changes.

To answer your question directly, yes: if you use

```
<MyComponent {...props} />
```

Then any change in any member of `props` will trigger a rerender, even if it is not used by `MyComponent`.